# What size prehung door to buy

Tags: doors, interior

I have to replace two, interior doors in my old house, which was built in 1973.  The existing doors are 29-1/2 inches wide and their door frames are soft MDF that falls apart when I drive a screw through it.  The screws for the hinges are pulling out and I tried to replace them with 3-1/2 inch screws but they found no studs to bite into.  So I want to replace them with prehung doors.

I looked online at Lowe's and their doors are 30 inches wide.  Are my doors an odd size or is 29-1/2 inches the actual width of a 30-inch door?

Comment: After a little research, it looks like I have a weird door size (sigh.)  I was hoping to get by for cheap.

Comment: Are you measuring the size of the door itself or the size of the jamb from side to side?

Comment: @AlaskaMan I was measuring the door itself.  Since posting this, I measured the jams and there appears to be room to install a 30-inch door if I move a couple of studs.  I have room to do that, so I think I will just buy 30-inch, prehung doors.

Comment: If you take the trim off around the door then you can measure the side of the opening,  that is Called the Ro, rough opening. The RO For a 30 inch door Will be approximately 32. You should be able to get an off-the-shelf door to fit your rough opening. You can always make the opening a little smaller If you need to.

Comment: if the 3" screws didn't reach you have plenty of room.

Answer (score 1):

I think my 29-1/2-inch doors are an unusual size.  From my research, it appears that 30-inch doors are an actual, 30 inches wide.  So that answers my question.  I think I will just buy 30-inch doors and widen the opening a bit, if needed, by moving the studs.

Comment: You shouldn't have to move any studs. As Alaska Man said just measure the rough opening and buy accordingly.

Comment: This _is_ the correct answer. Please don't forget to give yourself a check mark! As a side note, if you tried driving 3" screws through the jamb and _still_ didn't reach stud, A) something's really weird, and B) you could probably install a 36" door by trimming back your wall material on each side but not moving framing. They're a bit more expensive, but they make moving furniture _much_ easier. Something to consider as you head to the store.

Comment: When you remove the old door and jamb you will almost certainly find that the rough opening is large enough for a 30" prehung door. Installing a prehung door is not trivial, but if you want to try, you need to view some online videos. Consider having a competent carpenter do this.

Comment: This whole house has been weird.  I found all kinds of code violations (that I had to fix) when I remodeled the kitchen.  Previous owners probably didn't get permits when they did things.